# remote desktop on host

Tags: remote, vnc, ssh-tunneling

I have a host and I need people from Europe to access application on its desktop. So far I have told them to use `ssh -x -C user@host` and then launch an application with `application&` to get the app transferred to their desktop. That works, but they were complaining about the speed. Now I thought `VNC` might work better. so I installed a vncserver `Xvnc4` and I can connect to `127.0.0.1:5902` from the local shell but how can I tunnel this through ssh from external?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssh -L 5902:localhost:5902 user@host

Where first 5902 is local port of the client, localhost is the server and second 5902 is the servers port which is vnc port.

Then users(clients) can use vns from their local 5902